# Very Basic Function to compare strings or numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I want to create a Custom Function in my google sheet, which will take few inputs and compare them below is the example please:

I know this is very simple but when I try to save this code this give me the below error.

> Missing ; before statement. (line 6, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: function TESTFUN(A1,B1,C1) {
  var str1 = A1;
  var str2 = B1;
  var int = C1;
  
If (str1 == "Lion") {
then
If (str2 == "Cheeta"){
then
If ( int = 1 ) {
then
return "Cat_Family_Exists";
}
else {
return "False";
}

Comment: Do A1, B1 and C1 describe the values where you want to pull your input from?

Comment: If my post answered your question, I'd be thankful if you could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can be written in plain JavaScript for Google Apps Script:

```
function testFunction(A1,B1,C1) { 
        // check if all the three conditions are met
     if (A1 == "Lion" && B1 == "Cheeta" && C1 == 1) {
        // if they're met, return Cat_Family_Exists
       return "Cat_Family_Exists"; }
        // else return Cheeta
       else {
       return "Cheeta";
         };

};
```

However, if you want to directly get the data out of a sheet, you might want to have a look at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).

Comment: Super!! How do I club AND and OR conditions? Like, IF ( A1 == "Lion" && B1 == "Cheeta" OR "Tiger" && C1 == 1)

Comment: The logical operators in JavaScript are explained in quite a lot of detail in various tutorials. You might want to have a look at the MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: I followed the link provided however when I am trying to do the below its giving FALSE "Cheeta:
 function testFunction(A1,B1,C1,D1) { 
        // check if all the three conditions are met
     if (A1 == "Lion" && B1 == "Cheeta" && (C1 == 1 || D1 == 2)){
        // if they're met, return Cat_Family_Exists
       return "Cat_Family_Exists"; }
        // else return Cheeta
       else {
       return "Cheeta";
         };

}; any help?